# How to implement SEQUENCE as specified in an RFC

Tags: rfc

I've only recently started reading RFC's when I want to know something about a certain protocol, and I can't seem to find where I can find the RFC that defines the basic datatypes/keywords used in RFC's. I want the definition, because I want to make sure something is implemented 100% according to standard down to the bytes as separators (e.g. newline or space), etc.

An example, I want to know how following definition is implemented (from RFC 5280):

```
   Validity ::= SEQUENCE {
        notBefore      Time,
        notAfter       Time }

   Time ::= CHOICE {
        utcTime        UTCTime,
        generalTime    GeneralizedTime }
```

Is sequence used purely to group "notBefore" and "notAfter" and separate them with a comma?

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging I discovered this is the [Abstract syntax notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example_encoded_in_DER) ASN.1 notation and is described in [RFC 3641](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3641) and [RFC 4792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4792).